# Grunt-Watch not running the tasks after few iterations

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-sass

I have seen many issues which are related to this, but I haven't found the desired solution.

**Problem :**
While I am working with sass files or js files in my project, I want to compile/jshint those files when they were changed. So I am using **grunt-contrib-watch** to do this. It is working fine, but after some files changed, It is tracking the file changes, but It stops compiling( stops running the task, which has to run when the file changes ).

**Code :**

```
 module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        config: {
            PROJECT_DIR: "Project"
        },
        sass: {
            current: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    lineNumber: true,
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                    update: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: []
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= config.PROJECT_DIR %>**/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:current'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    debounceDelay: 2000
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.PROJECT_DIR %>**/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    debounceDelay: 2000
                }
            }
        }
    });



    grunt.event.many('watch', 10, function (action, filepath, target) {
        var paths = new cleanPaths(filepath);
        var filepath = paths.filepath;
        var dirpath = paths.dirpath;
        switch (target) {

        case 'sass':
            if (grunt.file.isMatch(grunt.config('watch.sass.files'), filepath)) {
                grunt.config('sass.current.src', filepath);
                grunt.config('sass.current.dest', filepath.replace('sass/', 'css/').replace('.scss', '.css'));
                // pushFile(filepath, filepath.replace('sass/', 'css/').replace('.scss', '.css'));
            }
            break;

        case 'js':
            if (grunt.file.isMatch(grunt.config('watch.js.files'), filepath)) {
                grunt.config('jshint.all', [filepath]);
                // pushFile(filepath)
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
};
```

I am dynamically updating the sass configs( src and dest values).

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "Gruntfile.js",
    "scripts": {},
    "author": "",
    "license": "",
    "description": "",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

**Console image link** : https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8776227/16587119/b7bfb332-42e6-11e6-8281-789ef60d22ec.png

Stops compiling even when, there is no error in the sass code.

I am using latest version of grunt-contrib-watch plugin.

Comment: can you provide your package.json and full grunt file? thank you